# Expansive path expressions in quoted triples?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb, rdf-star

I'm trying to query something like wikipedia where objects connect to one another and the edges have the paragraph which links them. I'm hoping to wrap my head around the query portions before I figure out the semantic values for the links and entities.

Data set looks like this currently (may change eventually):

```
PREFIX : <http://justin.abrah.ms/knowledge_base#>

:SteamCooked :title "Steaming" .

:KoreanFood 
  :title "Korean Food" ;
  :linksTo :SteamCooked
  .

:AlternativeMedicine :title "Alternative Medicine" .

:Cheong
  :title "Cheong (food)";
  :linksTo :KoreanFood;
  :linksTo :AlternativeMedicine .


<< :Cheong :linksTo :KoreanFood >> :inParagraph "Cheong (청; 淸) is a name for various sweetened foods in the form of syrups, marmalades, and fruit preserves. In Korean cuisine, cheong is used as a tea base, as a honey-or-sugar-substitute in cooking, as a condiment, and also as an alternative medicine to treat the common cold and other minor illnesses." .

<< :Cheong :linksTo :AlternativeMedicine >> :inParagraph "Cheong (청; 淸) is a name for various sweetened foods in the form of syrups, marmalades, and fruit preserves. In Korean cuisine, cheong is used as a tea base, as a honey-or-sugar-substitute in cooking, as a condiment, and also as an alternative medicine to treat the common cold and other minor illnesses." .
```

---

I can query for the connections with this sparql query:

```
PREFIX : <http://justin.abrah.ms/knowledge_base#>

SELECT ?midNode WHERE {
    ?am :title "Alternative Medicine" .
    ?steam :title "Steaming" .
    ?am (:linksTo|^:linksTo)* ?midNode .
  ?midNode (:linksTo|^:linksTo)* ?steam .
}
```

What I *can't* seem to figure out is how one would query for those nodes alongside the edges. The big hiccup I've found is that path expansion like `(:linksTo|^:linksTo)*` doesn't work inside quoted triples.  Is this a limitation of sparql? Or am I just missing a key concept?

Comment: what would be nodes "alongside the edges" in your example?

Comment: also, it's correct that path expressions aren't allowd in SPARQL Star, but you could extract the components of the SPARQL Star triple patterns with functions, e.g. given a RDF Star term bound to a variable `?term`, maybe identified by a filter with `FILTER(isTRIPLE(?term))` to get the subject part you can call `BIND(SUBJECT(?term) AS ?s)` and then use that `?s` in a normal triple pattern with the path expression, i.e. `?s (:linksTo|^:linksTo)* ?o`

Answer (score 3):

Credit to [uninformeduser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser) above, I ended up with this query which will correctly give me the pathing information with the associated paragraphs.

```
PREFIX : <http://justin.abrah.ms/knowledge_base#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?s ?o ?paragraph WHERE {
    ?am :title "Alternative Medicine" .
    ?kf :title "Korean Food" .
    
    ?term :inParagraph ?paragraph .
    filter(rdf:isTriple(?term)) .
    bind(rdf:subject(?term) as ?s) .
    bind(rdf:object(?term) as ?o) .
    filter(rdf:subject(?term) = ?midNode)
    
    ?am (:linksTo|^:linksTo)* ?midNode .
    ?midNode (:linksTo|^:linksTo)* ?kf .
    
    filter(?midNode = ?s) .
}
```

In my own understanding, this query says:

Decompose an `:inParagraph` subject, extracing the subject and object from it's left side.

Find a way to link term A (`?am`) with term B (`?kf`) through a yet-to-be-known `?midNode`.

Ensure `?midnode` is contained in our `:inParagraph` entries.